# How to set URLVariables parameters from an object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a URLVariables object (variables) that I'm setting its properties this way.

```
variables.fname = "fname";
variables.lname = "lname";
variables.address = "address";
```

But the properties differ so I want to just pass an object in the following format and have it set the property names and values correctly.

```
{fname: "fname", lname: "lname", address: "address"}
```

I tried a forloop like this, but it's not working. Not sure exactly how I achieve the same thing as setting the properties manually.

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables ();
for(var key:String in params){
   variables.key = String(params[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply do like this:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
for(var key:String in params){
   variables[key] = String(params[key]);
}
```

Comment: I have to wait 3 more minutes. There's some kind of a limit set here, but I upvoted already, thanks :)